# Firebase listener downloads data after leaving and getting back to screen

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

I implemented a chatscreen inside my app and the following code represents the important sample of the code and I noticed that something about the data usage is very odd. The code is a little bit longer code sample but I will explain it after that.

```js
    const CountryChat = props =>{
        var chosenLanguage = useSelector(state => state.myLanguage.myLanguage);
        const countryId = props.navigation.getParam("countryId");//already upper case so no worries about correct firestore adress
        const countryName = props.navigation.getParam("countryName");
        const userId = useSelector(state => state.auth.userId);
        const [TItext, setTItext] = useState("");
        const [chatmessages, setChatMessages] = useState(() => []);//dummydata so FlatList wont crash because messages are empty during first renderprocess
        const [refreshFlatlist, setRefreshFlatList] = useState(false);
        const [myProfilePic, setMyProfilePic] = useState(null);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            downloadProfilePic();
            var loadnewmessages = firebase.firestore().collection("group_rooms").doc("group_rooms").collection(`${countryId}`).orderBy("timestamp").limit(30).onSnapshot((snapshot)  => {
                var newmessages = [];
                var deletedmesssages = [];
                snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
                    if(change.type  === "added"){
                        newmessages.push({
                            counter: change.doc.data().counter,
                            sender: change.doc.data().sender,
                            timestamp: change.doc.data().timestamp.toString(),
                            value: change.doc.data().value,
                            displayedTime: new Date(change.doc.data().displayedTime),
                            senderProfilePic: change.doc.data().senderProfilePic
                        })
                    };
                    if(change.type  === "removed"){
                        deletedmesssages.push({
                            counter: change.doc.data().counter,
                            sender: change.doc.data().sender,
                            timestamp: change.doc.data().timestamp.toString(),
                            value: change.doc.data().value,
                            displayedTime: new Date(change.doc.data().displayedTime),
                            senderProfilePic: change.doc.data().senderProfilePic
                        })
                    };
    
                })
                if(newmessages.length > 0){
                    setChatMessages(chatmessages => {
                        return chatmessages.concat(newmessages)
                    });
                };
                if(deletedmesssages.length > 0){
                    setChatMessages(chatmessages => {
                        var modifythisarray = chatmessages;
                        let index = chatmessages.map(e => e.timestamp).indexOf(`${deletedmesssages[0].timestamp}`);
                        let pasttime = Date.now() - parseInt(modifythisarray[index].timestamp);
                        modifythisarray.splice(index, 1);
                        if(pasttime > 300000){
                            return chatmessages
                        }else{
                            return modifythisarray
                        }
                    });
                    setRefreshFlatList(refreshFlatlist => {
                        //console.log("Aktueller Status von refresher: ", refreshFlatlist);
                        return !refreshFlatlist
                    });
                }
                newmessages = [];
                deletedmesssages = [];
            });
    
            return () => { //for removing listeners
                try{
                    loadnewmessages();
                }catch(error){console.log(error)};
            }
        }, []);
    
    
        const pushMessagetoDB = async (filter, imageName) => {
            //sending message to the chatroom in Firestore
            if(filter == 1){
                await firebase.firestore().collection("group_rooms").doc("group_rooms").collection(`${countryId}`).add({
                    "counter": 1,
                    "sender": userId,
                    "timestamp": Date.now(),
                    "value": TItext,
                    "displayedTime": (new Date()).toISOString(),
                    "senderProfilePic": myProfilePic
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Chat written in DB!");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error writing Chat into DB: ", error);
                });
            }else{
                await firebase.firestore().collection("group_rooms").doc("group_rooms").collection(`${countryId}`).add({
                    "counter": 2,
                    "sender": userId,
                    "timestamp": Date.now(),
                    "senderProfilePic": myProfilePic,
                    "value": await firebase.storage().ref(`countrychatimages/${countryId}/${imageName}`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                        return url
                    }).catch((error) => { //incase something bad happened
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log("Image passed to DB!");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error passing Image to DB: ", error);
                });
            }
        };
```

What you can see here is my listener `loadnewmessages` which is beeing called inside my useEffect. This listener downloads the recent 30 messages in the chat and stores them in a state. The chat works perfect and I can even send a message (store a document on the firestore inside a collection which represents the chat). After I leave the screen the `return` in the useEffect is fired and my listener is getting canceled.

**My problem is**: I went back and forth around 4 times and I had 6 messages in my collection. After I did that I closed my app and checked my usage in "Usage and billing" in firebase and saw that suddenly I had around 25 reads. I was expecting that my listener will only download the collection with the documents once and will maintain in on the phone even if I leave the screen, not that I **redownload it always** when I check the screen, that is what I assume is happening after I saw my usage in my firebase console. If I launch my app and I receive 100 or more users, my billings will explode this way.

I know that I detach my listener and relaunch it but I expected firebase to maintain the already loaded data on the phone so I (if no new files will be written) I only get 1 read because the query run without loading any new data.

Can somebody pls explain to me what I did wrong or how I could improve my code to shrink down the reads? How can I change my code so it stays efficient and does not download already loaded data? Its really important for me to maintain the reads on a low level, I have big problems getting this under control and my money is very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the intended behavior. When you switch your pages/activities the listener is closed. A listener will fetch all the matching documents specified in query when it's reconnected (just like being connected for first time) as mentioned in the docs:

> An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document snapshot.

You can try:

- Enabling offline persistence which caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline. If the documents are fetched from the cache then you won't be charged reads. However I am not sure if this will be the best option for your use case.
- Storing messages fetched so far in local storage of that platform and then query messages sent after message using the listener. You would have to remove messages from local storage if any message is deleted.

```js
const messagesRef = db..collection("group_rooms").doc("group_rooms").collection(`${countryId}`);

return messagesRef.doc("last_local_msg_id").get().then((doc) => {
    // Get all messages sent after last local msg
    const newMessagesQuery = messagesRef
        .orderBy("timestamp")
        .startAt(doc)
        .limit(30);
});
```

Using for example async storage suits good, even increasing the size of the memory of async storage is not a problem so that its possible to store more data and therefore more chats as [showed here.](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/db_size/)

Comment: I would really like to use the persistence feature but it was explained to me that it is enabled by default (obviously it is not...) and its even written in the official docs: "For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default." Got it from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline?hl=en

Comment: @KubaghettothefreshTestobun it's totally your call which method to go with. In my opinion, storing message locally yourself kind of gives you more control over what you are storing.

Comment: The Problem is that I could use a redux store but then the data would be lost when I close and reopen my app. The other solution would be to use async-storage but the limit of it is only 6MB which is not good for this purpose.

Comment: @KubaghettothefreshTestobun redux is more for state management... local storage is persistent in browser (or any platform you are using)

Comment: The only thing I can find as a module for react native is async storage, do you know where I find this "local storage" youre mentioning? Or is it even a module or what do you mean by that?

Comment: @KubaghettothefreshTestobun so web apps use browser's local storage. I looked up for React Native and they recommend using AsyncStorage instead of it. So that's what I am referring to. You can store all message like: `past_messages: JSON.stringify(messages)`

Comment: Well that is an option indeed but as I mentioned, AsyncStorage is kapped at 6MB. I dont think this is a good solution considering multiple chat rooms and already storing other data inside there like userData, location, login credentials etc which is already consuming this 6MB space partially. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: @KubaghettothefreshTestobun 6 MB seems to be storing a lots of messages tbh. You can maybe store just last 100 message per chat or something and then make requests to database as required. It's still better than making 25 calls every time?

Comment: Well... fair enough  One last question. Why did you say that firestore persistence isnt the best solution for me in this case? Was quite wondering because of that, is there a reason?

Comment: @KubaghettothefreshTestobun you'll have more control over what you store and what you can remove using async storage.